# React "State Hook" got automatically reassigned without using setState() method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

this is my first question in this forum. I hope I can describe my problem correctly.

I have a state hook called persons:
`const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])`

My goal is to re-render the "persons" array after making a PUT Request. My Code works as intended, but I don't understand why the "persons" array gets automatically reassigned even though I don't use the setPersons() method.

```
if(window.confirm(`${newPerson.name} is already added to the phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`))
      {
        console.log('update person:',newPerson)
        personsService.updatePerson(newPerson)
                      .then(response => console.log(`${response.name}'s number has been updated`))
           
        //update persons list locally  
        persons.map(person=>{
          person.id === newPerson.id ? person.number = newPerson.number : person //why does this code work without setPersons??
        })
       //when I don't use this map function, the array doesn't get automatically re-assigned
```

Thanks in advance!

My full code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import PersonForm from './components/PersonForm'
import Persons from './components/Persons'
import personsService from './services/persons'

const App = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])
  //useEffect is executed after all components have been rendered
  //this is why console.log("Execute the other codes...") was executed before console.log("fetching data from the server...")
  //despite the code order
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("fetching data from the server...")
    personsService.getPersons()
      .then(response=>{
        console.log("Data have been fetched successfully!")
        console.log("Data: ", response)
        console.log("Update Persons state...")
        setPersons(response)
    })
  },[])

  console.log("Execute the other codes...")

  console.log("Initial state of persons state is: ",persons)
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [telNumber, setTelNumber] = useState('')
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')
  
//Event handler
  const onChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  const deleteHandler = (id,name) =>{
    console.log('Auaaa',id)
    if(window.confirm(`Delete ${name}?`))
    {
      personsService.deletePerson(id)
      const arrayAfterDeletion = persons.filter(person=>person.id !== id)
      setPersons(arrayAfterDeletion)
      
      
    }

  }


  const telChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    setTelNumber(event.target.value)
  }

  const filterChangeHandler= (event) =>{
    setFilter(event.target.value)
  }

  const onClickHandler = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const newPerson = {id:newName, name:newName, number:telNumber} 

    //check persons list, whether it contais the same person (same name & number)
    let containsTheSamePerson = false
  
    persons.forEach(person=>{
      //doesn't make sense here if we compare the objects (always different because the id)
      if(person.name === newPerson.name)
      {
        containsTheSamePerson = true
      }

    })

    if(!containsTheSamePerson)
    {
      const newPersonList = persons.concat(newPerson)
      //console.log('old list', persons)
      //console.log('new list',newPersonList);
      setPersons(newPersonList)

      //push new person to the server
      personsService.addNewPerson(newPerson)
                  .then(response => console.log(`${response.name} has been added to database`))
    
      setNewName('')
      setTelNumber('')
    }else{
      //alert(`${newPerson.name} is already added to the phonebook`)
      if(window.confirm(`${newPerson.name} is already added to the phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`))
      {
        console.log('update person:',newPerson)
        personsService.updatePerson(newPerson)
                      .then(response => console.log(`${response.name}'s number has been updated`))
           
        //update persons list locally  
        persons.map(person=>{
          person.id === newPerson.id ? person.number = newPerson.number : person //why does this code work withour setPersons??
        })
        
      
        setNewName('')
        setTelNumber('')

      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <Filter value = {filter} onChangeHandler = {filterChangeHandler}/>
      <h3>Add a new</h3>
     
      <PersonForm nameValue={newName} nameChangeHandler={onChangeHandler} 
                  numValue={telNumber} numChangeHandler={telChangeHandler} 
                  buttonHandler={onClickHandler}/>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <Persons list = {persons} filter = {filter} onClickDelete={deleteHandler}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Is the `persons` array *itself* being re-assigned?  Or are objects *within* the array being mutated?  (Specifically the `number` property)

Comment: When I tried to console.log the persons array (before and after .map method), the objects with number updated are mutated. My intention was to create a new array with this map function and then calling setPersons() to rerender the array.

Comment: *"the objects with number updated are mutated"* - Well, yes.  That's what this does: `person.number = newPerson.number`  It assigns a new value to the `number` property of that object.  So after doing that, the objects in the array have new values assigned to that property.  (The array itself hasn't changed, only the objects it references.)  You certainly *shouldn't* mutate state in React.  But I guess it's not clear to me why you're surprised that the objects are mutated after you mutate them...

Comment: Hi @David thank you for your answer. But array.map() should return a new array right? I know that we shouldn't directly mutate the state. I mean, how does my app (with persons array inside) get re-rendered, even though I don't calling the setPersons()?

Comment: *"array.map() should return a new array right?"* - It does.  Though (1) your new array would be filled with `undefined` values and (2) you don't do anything with that new array.  *"I know that we shouldn't directly mutate the state."* - Indeed, so don't.  *"how does my app (with persons array inside) get re-rendered"* - Because you also update other state values after the call to `.map()`.  Updating state triggers a re-render.  Mutating state does not.  Your code is both updating state **and** mutating state.

Answer (score 1):

`persons` does not change; it remains the same array reference. But you modified the objects inside the array, which you are NOT supposed to do. You must not directly mutate your state in React, but it is also not going to check if you did so.

When you then call `setNewName`, a rerender is queued and your function component is called again, this time using the modified objects to generate the output.

Comment: but array.map() function should return a new array, right? My plan was to create a new array with updated values and then calling the setPersons(newUpdatedArray) method.

Comment: @JavaInsel It does create a new array, but you didn't use the return value. You directly modified the objects inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the array are mutated (the array *itself* doesn't change) because that's exactly what you're doing here:

```
person.number = newPerson.number
```

This sets a new value to the `number` property of that object.  So after doing this in a `.map()` call (which is a mis-use of `.map()` by the way, looping over an array to perform an operation should be with a loop or `.forEach()`), that property is updated on those objects.

*Coincidentally* the component also re-renders because you also update other state values:

```
setNewName('')
setTelNumber('')
```

So you're mutating one state (which you should never do in React) and updating another state.  The result is that the component re-renders and both states have new data.  One was just updated incorrectly.

In a comment above you also mention:

> My intention was to create a new array with this map function and then calling setPersons()

If that's your intent then do that.  For example:

```
setPersons(persons.map(person => (
  person.id === newPerson.id ?
    { ...person, number: newPerson.number } : person
)));
```

Some key differences here are:

1. State is not mutated.  For objects which need a new property value set, a new object instance is returned with all of the properties of the existing instance plus the one updated one.
2. The `.map()` callback returns objects so the `.map()` operation itself produces a new array of objects.  (In your code nothing is returned so `.map()` produces an array of `undefined` values, which is also ignored.)
3. That new array of objects is passed to `setPersons` to update state.

Comment: I finally understand what the problem is! Thank you so much for your help @David :)